# Grain of sand in apple watch circular side hole - effect / removal option?

Tags: apple-watch

I have a grain of sand in the endmost of the two tiny circular holes on the side of the apple watch due to imprudent behaviour at the beach.

Does this matter? If so, is there a way to remove it? I am hesitant to stick a pin in the hole to try to remove it as my feeling is this probably won't work and also may make it worse.

I am not aware of any effect on function at this point.

Comment: can you add a picture

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it affects your watch but you can hold that area in front of a vacuum cleaner hose to suck out the sand. Hold the watch securely if you try his.

Comment: This is exactly what I’d recommend too.

Comment: If the regular vacuum nozzle doesn't get it, take a piece of paper (or thicker paper), cut/poke a small hole in it, then put that against the vacuum hose so the small hole is the only opening for the suction. It'll create more sucking power and may help.